# Invoking R scripts from Spark Java on Windows fails with Cannot run program

Tags: r, windows, spark-java

> Application fails with java.io.IOException: Cannot run program
>   "C:\Users..\Temp\spark-70bf05bd-6b8a-4c9f-b256-edbfb5f687b7\userFiles-cadcc324-4e7f-4952-8ec2-f442c7bd1cf8\finddistance.R":
>   CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application

**Note: This is an example from Orielly's "Learning Spark" chapter 6 from https://github.com/databricks/learning-spark/blob/master/src/main/java/com/oreilly/learningsparkexamples/java/ChapterSixExample.java**

**Spark Java Code invoking R script**

```
Example 6-18. Driver program using pipe() to call finddistance.R in Java 
    //JavaPairRDD<String, CallLog[]> contactsContactLists;

    // Compute the distance of each call using an external R program 
    // adds our script to a list of files for each node to download with this job 
    String distScript = "./src/R/finddistance.R"; 
    String distScriptName = "finddistance.R"; 
    sc.addFile(distScript);
    JavaRDD<String> pipeInputs = contactsContactLists.values().map(new VerifyCallLogs()).flatMap(
          new FlatMapFunction<CallLog[], String>() { public Iterable<String> call(CallLog[] calls) {
              ArrayList<String> latLons = new ArrayList<String>();
              for (CallLog call: calls) {
                latLons.add(call.mylat + "," + call.mylong +
                            "," + call.contactlat + "," + call.contactlong);
              }
              return latLons;
            }
          });

    JavaRDD<String> distances = pipeInputs.pipe(SparkFiles.get(distScriptName)); 
    System.out.println(StringUtils.join(distances.collect(), ","));
```

**R script**

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript
library("Imap")
f <- file("stdin")
open(f)
while(length(line <- readLines(f,n=1)) > 0) {
  # process line
  contents <- Map(as.numeric, strsplit(line, ","))
  mydist <- gdist(contents[[1]][1], contents[[1]][2], contents[[1]][3], contents[[1]][4],
                  units="m", a=6378137.0, b=6356752.3142, verbose = FALSE)
  write(mydist, stdout())
}
```

**Stack Trace**

```
    java.io.IOException: Cannot run program"C:\Users\..\AppData\Local\Temp\spark-70bf05bd-6b8a-4c9f-b256-edbfb5f687b7\userFiles-cadcc324-4e7f-4952-8ec2-f442c7bd1cf8\finddistance.R": CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PipedRDD.compute(PipedRDD.scala:119)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:203)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:386)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:137)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
```